# Postfix sending outgoing emails back to me via virtual_alias_maps

Tags: postfix, regex

I have a postfix mailserver set up to forward all emails to my domain, `*@example.com`, to a single virtual mailbox: `me@example.com`.

I did that with this configuration:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf regexp:/etc/postfix/aliases-regexp
```

**/etc/postfix/aliases-regexp**
(should forward anything *not* already going to `me@example.com`)

```
!/me@example\.com/ me@example.com
```

Receiving mail works fine:

```
postfix/smtpd[5852]: connect from unknown[108.60.212.145]
postfix/trivial-rewrite[5856]: warning: do not list domain example.com in BOTH virtual_mailbox_domains and relay_domains
postfix/smtpd[5852]: E7D49E27: client=unknown[108.60.212.145]
postfix/cleanup[5857]: E7D49E27: message-id=<a197d7118eaedfb5@be0fdfd65ca8aeb2>
postfix/qmgr[5787]: E7D49E27: from=<test@ismyemailworking.com>, size=1700, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtpd[5852]: disconnect from unknown[108.60.212.145] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
postfix/pickup[5785]: 64CB91090: uid=1002 from=<test@ismyemailworking.com>
postfix/cleanup[5857]: 64CB91090: message-id=<a197d7118eaedfb5@be0fdfd65ca8aeb2>
postfix/qmgr[5787]: 64CB91090: from=<test@ismyemailworking.com>, size=2068, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/trivial-rewrite[5856]: warning: do not list domain example.com in BOTH virtual_mailbox_domains and relay_domains
postfix/pipe[5858]: E7D49E27: to=<me@example.com>, orig_to=<test8@example.com>, relay=spamassassin, delay=0.54, delays=0.13/0.01/0/0.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
postfix/qmgr[5787]: E7D49E27: removed
postfix/lmtp[5862]: 64CB91090: to=<mail@example.com>, relay=fqdn.example.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.08, delays=0.02/0.03/0.02/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <mail@example.com> 22w5HOfOilvnFgAASQqZ1w Saved)
postfix/qmgr[5787]: 64CB91090: removed
```

Note the line:

```
postfix/pipe[5858]: E7D49E27: to=<me@example.com>, orig_to=<test@example.com>, relay=spamassassin, delay=0.54, delays=0.13/0.01/0/0.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
```

Showing that the message was intended for `test@example.com` but was delivered to `me@example.com`.  This is good.  Unfortunately, it happens on the way out too.  This causes outgoing messages to be sent back to me.

```
postfix/lmtp[5862]: BA93CE27: to=<me@example.com>, orig_to=<test@ismyemailworking.com>, relay=fqdn.example.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.22, delays=0.19/0/0.02/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <me@example.com> QzBoOSXPiluGGAAASQqZ1w Saved)
```

Here's the full log when sending mail:

```
postfix/trivial-rewrite[5856]: warning: do not list domain example.com in BOTH virtual_mailbox_domains and relay_domains
postfix/submission/smtpd[6260]: BA93CE27: client=mail-pl1-f178.google.com[209.85.214.178], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=me@example.com
postfix/cleanup[5857]: BA93CE27: message-id=<CAHgoK_pUF=7qQ+fCRYcqKBPGqxK1fin-AjjoY5xr0GuUeDScow@mail.gmail.com>
postfix/qmgr[5787]: BA93CE27: from=<me@example.com>, size=4192, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/trivial-rewrite[5856]: warning: do not list domain example.com in BOTH virtual_mailbox_domains and relay_domains
postfix/lmtp[5862]: BA93CE27: to=<me@example.com>, orig_to=<test@ismyemailworking.com>, relay=fqdn.example.com[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.22, delays=0.19/0/0.02/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <me@example.com> QzBoOSXPiluGGAAASQqZ1w Saved)
postfix/qmgr[5787]: BA93CE27: removed
```

The result is that my messages don't appear to send, and I don't even get an error back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options for creating a catch-all for a domain in Postfix, yours being rather complicated. The usual way is to have `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual` with `@example.com me`. Remember to `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` when using `hash:`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing `/etc/postfix/aliases-regexp` to:

```
if /(.*)@example.com/
!/me@example\.com/ me@example.com
endif
```

The if statement first checks if the mail is going to the domain, which excludes outgoing mail.